# Whats the importance of Import vs Link Method to include css file?

Tags: css

Added Questions

Q.1-Whats the Difference Between Import VS Link Method to include css file ?

Q.2-Whats the Benefits/Disadvantages Between Import VS Link Method to include css file ?

Q.3-Which one is usually Preferred and Why ?

Comment: [StackOverflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553)

Answer (score 1):

1. The `link` tag is used to reference external style sheets from HTML. The `import` keyword is used to reference style sheets from within CSS.
2. The advantage of using the `link` tag is that when CSS references are loaded, they are non-blocking. `import` will cause CSS to be loaded one at a time - which can affect page-load performance.
3. For the reason above `link` is very much preferred over `import`.

[This article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/) by Steve Souders sums up the answers to all three of your questions, and any other queries you might have.

Comment: +'d for the nice link provided!